# Chrome flexbox 100% height inside other 100% height flexbox overflows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a full height page using flexboxes, where the content also uses a flexbox. The page should look as follows [example of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7spk.png). The blue div is dynamic and could change in height and the red content should take up the remaining space of the content div. This works on both Firefox and IE, however on Chrome it overflows. Can somebody explain why it overflows on Chrome?

The HTML is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="fill"></div>
                <div class="dynamic">Here is some dynamic content<br>Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS is:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: #ccc;
    flex: none;
}
.content{
    background-color: #333;
    flex: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.dynamic{
    background-color: #0066ff;
    flex: none;
}
.fill{
    flex: auto;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.content`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated snippet.

Use `flex:1` for the container that needs to adjust the height automatically.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 10px solid #333;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dynamic {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  border: 10px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">Here is some dynamic content
      <br>Test</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, the problem however is that the container div inside the content div get loaded dynamically, so it should still be inside this container div. Is it possible to keep the seem HTML structure and still don't have it overflow on Chrome?